# when to use have been

Tags: progressive-aspect, perfect-constructions

I have read that we use "have been" with the present perfect continuous as in the formula [has/have + been + present participle], e.g.,

> You have been waiting here for two hours.

But sometimes I read sentences formed as [has/have + been + v3], e.g.,

> the forest has been cleared .

I am confused about what the second formula is and in which cases we should use it.

Comment: The latter example is incorrect. _The forest has been cleared_ is fine; it is an example of the passive usage.

Comment: I've corrected the example.

Comment: It's still incorrect. "The forest has been cleared" or "They have been clearing the forest" would both be possible, but "They have been cleared the forest" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39902/3281

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the difference between:

"They have been clearing the forest" and: 
"They have cleared the forest"?

If so, it's fairly simple: the continuous form ('-ing') implies 'continuation' i.e. the activity is still continuing or we simply don't know if the activity has finished yet. 'Have cleared' is clearly past tense. Therefore the activity ended.

Consider:

"They've been cleaning all day" (Have they finished? Don't know)
"They cleaned all day" (Have they finished? Yes)

Answer (score 1):

> **Present perfect simple or present perfect continuous?** We use the present perfect simple, not continuous:
>
> **1** if the action is finished and complete. **I've written a letter; I've learnt a new piece on the piano. I can play it now.**

---

**Present perfect continuous form**

*I've been learning Russian, but I can't speak it well.*

---

> **2** if we want to say how often an action has happened. **She's broken her leg three times.**
>
> **3** with state verbs (*like, love, know,* etc). **I've known Joe for years.** (NOT **I've been knowing Joe for years.**)