# "have stayed" or "had been staying" which one is correct?

Tags: tense

> I **have stayed** in your hotel for several days last month.
>   I **had been staying** in your hotel for several days last month.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Have been doing" and "have done"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39902/have-been-doing-and-have-done)

Comment: "have done" and "had done" are not the same, so it does nto seem that this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I have stayed in your hotel for several days last month**

This sentence is wrong because  present perfect can not be used for  time adverbials like last month.

You can say

> **I had/ stayed in your hotel for several days last month**

I stayed in your hotel for severaldays last month is the preferred form though.
past perfect is usualy not used for a single  event in the past.

> **I had been staying in your hotel  for  several days last month**

This sentence is correct.

Simple past or past perfect tells about the completed action in the past.

Past continuous or past perfect continuous tells about a continuous activity in the past

Comment: +1 for '*I stayed in your hotel*'

Answer (score 1):

Both convey a very similar meaning, which one you want to use will depend on the context of how you are using the phrase.

"I have stayed" is a statement of a current condition.  It is read to state that at the present time you are in a condition where you stayed in the hotel for several days last month.  It could be used to introduce a follow one statement in the present or future tense. For example:

> I have stayed in your hotel for several days last month and now I realise that you charge extra to clean the room.
>
> I have stayed in your hotel for several days last month and I now I will be returning next month.

"I had been staying" is a statement of a past condition and could be used to introduce a follow on statement in the past tense.  For example:

> I had been staying in your hotel for several days last month when I realised that you charge extra to clean the room.

Comment: I have stayed in your hotel  last  month   is  wrong.I  am  sure of  this.can any one  say  this is correct?